Self-hosted agent DevOps pipeline build failing because of powershell execution policy
I have a Self-hosted agent version (3.236.1), have 3 such agents.
DevOps pipeline builds are failing with error like below.
I went through lots of Microsoft articles to set Execution policy for current user, local machine, Machine policy etc.
If I set the policy for Current user or local machine its not working get same error as below
Build works only with if I set the Machine policy. Using
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell -Name ExectionPolicy -Value ByPass (or RemoteSighed)

However, this setting gets over-written after some time by org group policy.
Our IT is reluctant to change the Machine policy permanently for the agents to work.
Can anyone please suggest a permanent solution or work around for this problem.
There are lot of VSBuild scripts inside the parent directory c:\agent\agent01(02,03)_Work\Task...
Thanks
ERROR:
File C:\agent\agent01\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.231.0\ps_modules\Vsts
TaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psm1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\agent\agent01\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca
411ecda\1.231.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psm1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the 
current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies 
at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe', arguments '-NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if ([Console]::InputEncoding -is [Text.UTF8Encoding] -and [Console]::InputEncoding.GetPreamble().Length -ne 0) { [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false } if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; Import-Module -Name 'C:\agent\agent01\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.231.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' ; $DebugPreference = 'Continue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''C:\agent\agent01\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.231.0\VSBuild.ps1'''))"'.


The cause of the issue is that the psm1 files of the Pipeline task are not signed.

Can anyone please suggest a permanent solution or work around for this problem.

Since you don't want to set a policy to bypass it, I suggest you create a certificate to sign the relevant files.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Create Certificate on machine
$authenticode = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject “AZUR-SelfhostedAgent” -CertStoreLocation Cert:\\LocalMachine\\My -Type CodeSigningCert 

Step2: Copy Certificate to RootCA-Store
$rootStore = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new(“Root”,“LocalMachine”)  
$rootStore.Open(“ReadWrite”)  
$rootStore.Add($authenticode)  
$rootStore.Close()

Step3: Copy to TrustedPublisher-Store
$publisherStore = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new(“TrustedPublisher”,“LocalMachine”)  
$publisherStore.Open(“ReadWrite”)  
$publisherStore.Add($authenticode)  
$publisherStore.Close()

Step4: Check Certificates in all three stores
Get-ChildItem Cert:\\LocalMachine\\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq “CN=AZUR-SelfhostedAgent”}  
Get-ChildItem Cert:\\LocalMachine\\Root | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq “CN=AZUR-SelfhostedAgent”}  
Get-ChildItem Cert:\\LocalMachine\\TrustedPublisher | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq “CN=AZUR-SelfhostedAgent”}

For example:

Step5: Sign all the .psm1 files and .ps1 files of the Pipeline tasks.
For example:
$codeCertificate = Get-ChildItem Cert:\\LocalMachine\\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq “CN=AZUR-SelfhostedAgent”}  
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath “C:\agent\agent01\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.231.0\ps_modules\Vsts
TaskSdk\*.ps*” -Certificate $codeCertificate  
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath “C:\agent\agent01\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.231.0\*.ps1” -Certificate $codeCertificate  
  

Result sample:

Note: You need to run these commands in PowerShell Administrator mode.

Thanks @Kevin Lu-MSFT, I tried this solution till step 4, gave up on step 5, will do the last step 5 and see how it goes. Thanks a lot.

Just adding to my previous comment, this problem started happening recently. not sure how it worked before a month ago.

Hi Kevin, After doing step 5, build task is working fine but Build verification step fails because some Temporary powershell scripts files are generated in c:\agent01_temp\c9b8bb08-ddfe-4aa6-a15a-836b53a77ca3.ps1 which are not signed. I cannot see these files, may be generated during the execution of Build verification step. Not sure how to deal with such files which are generated on the fly.

@user2921973 I will do some test later and give you an update about the latest issue.

@user2921973 I have tested the vsbuild task and it can work as expected. If possible, can you create a new ticket and share more details about the current issue and the build definition? Then we can do further investigation on the new issue.

In my previous comment I already mentioned that Build task (VSBuild@1) works. Its the Build verification task which is failing while doing this PowerShell script


task: PowerShell@2
displayName: 'Build Verification'
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
Get-ChildItem "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" -Recurse                                                                 This task creates some temporary PowerShell Script files and error comes up The file
C:\agent_work_temp\879635e3-95db-4615-a7ae-107db204cdef.ps1 is not digitally signed. I will create a new ticket

